# Connect to Existing PSSession

Tags: powershell

Currently I am using [webJEA](https://github.com/markdomansky/WebJEA) internally to allow our service desk some administrative rights for o365 MFA.  In this case resetting MFA contact methods and viewing current users with MFA enabled.

The home page they hit runs an onload script that connects to to the required powershell sessions.  That script is

```
$adminCredential = "xxxxxxx"
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential - 
ArgumentList $adminCredential, $Pass

Write-Output "Connecting to Exchange Online Remote Powershell Service"
$ExoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
if ($null -ne $ExoSession) { 
    Import-PSSession $ExoSession -AllowClobber
} else {
    Write-Output "  No EXO service set up for this account"
}

Write-Output "Connecting to EOP Powershell Service"
$EopSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
if ($null -ne $EopSession) { 
    Import-PSSession $EopSession -AllowClobber
} else {
    Write-Output "  No EOP service set up for this account"
}


#This connects to Azure Active Directory
Connect-MsolService -Credential $cred
```

This runs every time the "home" page is loaded which can often result in long load times as it imports the required cmdlets and ETC.  It also outputs some error messages that indicate it cannot connect because the max connections have been reached yada yada.

How can I make the above script look if there is any existing PSsessions?

If there are open sessions not run the rest of the script.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Putting here: since it is too long for a comment character limits.

This is not a PowerShell code issue / limitation, but a security / operational boundary limitation.

Each session has an ID and Name even that is bound to the machine it was started on. If a user was connecting to a given host then an admin on that host can actually look and see that inbound connection. If this was not a http session, then you could get and reconnect to session that host has, this way...

```
# Get all PSRemoting sessions the target host
Get-PSSession -ComputerName MyServerName 

# Reconnect to all open sessions on the target host
Get-PSSession -ComputerName MyServerName | Connect-PSSession
```

Since this is Web, each user session, is unique (user tokens, cookies, yadda... yadda...), especially with the use of SSL, they must be. There is no way around that for obvious reasons and again, this is not a PowerShell limitation, it's simply how web / SSL sessions work.

Your users are coming from different workstations, potentially different browsers and establishing unique user sessions.

Being able to do this would fall into cross-site script vulnerably or cookies / browser session stealing. That should never be allowed.

Comment: the PSSession is already opened by the server/service.  Users authenticate via SSO/AD to the front end/website.  The site only acts as a front end for powershell. It allows them to execute scripts that are already pre-defined.

The issue i am running into is that there is a script that on page load, by any user opens a PSSession with credentials baked into the script already.  I'm looking for a way it can check if the session is already open before trying to connect/create a new one.